# Java Mapping tool (bean to bean)

Tags: java, mapping

I was looking to match domain objects to display objects using [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) but the project seems dead. Has anything replaced it? I really like the idea of annotation driven mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try JMapper:
http://code.google.com/p/jmapper-framework/
is much simpler and easy to set up and its performance is better than the dozer

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's dead?  I see some bugs and recent releases.  I am using it now and have been happy with it.

Comment: Last update over a year ago (March 12 2011): http://sourceforge.net/projects/dozer/files/

Answer (score 1):

Another option for Java 8+: http://erchu.github.io/bean-cp/ (disclaimer: I'm the author of this project)

Answer (score 0):

[Dozer GitHub](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/) is alive, feel free to post issues or contribute.

Answer (score 0):

Well Dozer doesn't looks like a dead project. But it's very stable and has a long history. 
If you really like the idea of annotation driven mapping, you should have a look to Selma http://xebia-france.github.io/selma/. This API provide an annotation processor that will generate the mapping code at compile time. 
Big advantage is that it is refactor proof and you'll be able to see exactly what the mapping code looks like.